# How to compare two DateTimePicker's values and change the 1st DateTimePicker's value to that of the 2nd

Tags: vb.net-2010, datetimepicker, date-comparison, custom-datetimepicker

i've been searching the net for ideas as to how to be able to do this and so far, i haven't got anything.

this is my code so far...

```
If dtp_warrantyExp.Value.Date > dtp_dateAcquired.Value.Date Then
        dtp_warrantyExp.Value = dtp_dateAcquired.Value
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not too far from the correct code. Here goes...

```
If dtp_warrantyExp.Value.Date > dtp_dateAcquired.Value.Date Then
        dtp_warrantyExp.Value = dtp_dateAcquired.Value.Date
End If
```

Comment: You are correct about that. I just tried it and it worked. Two things: 1. Did you try and the code I sent, and, did it work?
2. Try setting warranty expired date to a few days ahead of date acquired, and see what happens.
I believe you would have tried that already. But try again.

Comment: I did not try your code, just some common sense there. If you meant to include the OP, please use `@OP's name`, if you meant to reply to me, please include `@My name` next time. Thanks.